# devices on genymotion cannot be started

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

when I want to start the device a warning like this appears

[image: error GenyMotion]

what should i do to fix this?

Comment: have you done what the error message suggests to do?

Answer (score 0):

This message means you need virtualization enabled, some CPUs does supports it. You can check yours if have it or not by running this:

```
lscpu
```

The output would look like this:

[image]

If your CPU does support virtualization but still genymotion popping-up the error message, than you have to make sure it is enabled in BIOS, search for `Virtualization` option, and set it enabled.